# TeX integral support

Tags: support, mathjax

Recently while answering a question I had to write an integral which was something like this. The problem here is the integral symbol looks too small. I went through [the mathjax tutorial in this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) but couldn't find how to make this integral larger.

$$\int\frac{\left(\sqrt{(3u^2+1)^2-2u^2}\right)}{2\sqrt{u}}\,du$$

Any references to a broader $\TeX$ tutorial besides this specific question would be very helpful.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this closer to what you want?
$$
{\Large\int}\frac{\sqrt{(3u^2+1)^2-2u^2}}{2\sqrt{u}}\,\mathrm{d}u
$$
`{\Large\int}\frac{\sqrt{(3u^2+1)^2-2u^2}}{2\sqrt{u}}\,\mathrm{d}u`

Comment: ah yes. okay thanks that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Oh what perfect alignment with the integral sign and the integrand.
$${\large\int}{\small\dfrac{\sqrt{(3u^2+1)^2-2u^2}}{2\sqrt{u}}} \ \text{du}$$

> $\$\$${\large\int}{\small\dfrac{\sqrt{(3u^2+1)^2-2u^2}}{2\sqrt{u}}} \ \text{du}$\$\$$

Comment: oh we have a `\small` too?

Comment: Yep, we do. It does what you would expect a command like that to do: make the stuff it surrounds smaller

Comment: Yeah. One question though, `\left(` and `\right)` make parenthesis that are auto adjusting. Anything like that?

Comment: @Sabyasachi That was my first thought, to use \left and \right. But there is no \left or \right with integrals  as far as I know